# How do I add authenticated methods without explicitly stating an if else condition? (Codeigniter, PHP)

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

I have a controller (class) called events. Some methods, such as get should be accessible to all users(public). However, some methods such as add and edit should only be accessible to authenticated users.

Instead of:

```
public function add(){
//if user is logged in add event
}

public function edit(){
//if user is logged in edit event
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to implement this? Perhaps so the 'if the user is logged in' condition is checked automatically each time I call a method?(And it doesn't have to be explicitly stated each time).

I thought it may be possible to have a parent class for events that has the unauthenticated methods and then extend it to include authenticated methods but I'm not sure if/how that would work.

For reference, I have the following in my Events controller:

```
class Events extends MY_Controller{

    public function get(){
        echo "List of events";
    }

    public function add(){
        echo "Adding an event";
    }

    public function edit(){
        echo "Editing an event";
    }
}
```

Comment: in C#, we put attributes on the methods to check for authentication, but it looks like php doesn't have attributes.

Answer (score -1):

you can do something like this

```
class Events extends MY_Controller{

    public function get(){
        echo "List of events";
    }

    public function addedit($edit_id=0){

        // check login user first
        if(!$this->session->get('userid')){ redirect('login')}

        if($this->input->post('submit'))
        {
          if($edit_id==0)
          {
              // insert record
          }
          else
          {
             // Edit record using edit_id
          }
        }

      if($edit_id>0)
      {
       // get array record using edit_id to display in form 
       $data['record']=$this->MODEL->getRecordById($edit_id)
      }

        $this->load->view('addeditform',$data)

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't see the point of removing one authentication check and then add two "method" checks. I actually find this to be less readable, harder to maintain and with confusing URLs. What if he wants to delete with permission check? Are you renaming it to `AddEditDelete()`, adding another if and changing all URLs/routes?